# Praat for detecting not single vowels but vocals in a word

Tags: vowels, praat

So. I've started using this powerfull (though inconvenient) piece of software Praat. And when i try to measure my own vocals formants of single vowels and these of native speakers (spanish) we all hit near respective median values.

And when i start analyzing vowels in words, say lobo.
Female voice gives respectively   (553,1287)  (494,807) for first and second o.

Male voice (541,1134) , (505,1080)

My attempts

- (529,1235), (511,1120)
- (488,1292) , (500,1128)
- (514,1238) ,    (504,1165)

Mean values for spanish o (Quilis y Esgueva 1983): (474.5,888.4)

So, what's going on here and why the F2 shifts so much?

**Update:**

I mean this shift from f2 of a standalone vowel to f2 of the vowel in lobo of native speakers and mine.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "why the F2 shifts so much"? Do you mean going from the first [o] to the second [o] in everyone's renditions, or comparing the native speakers' F2s to yours, or comparing various repetitions of your own?

Comment: There are a lot of factors that influence what values you will get when measuring F2 in a vowel. It is difficult to assess which ones are at play in your specific case without getting more information. How are you measuring formant values (there are at least three different ways in Praat)? Where in the vowel are you measuring? What were the values for the different speakers in the standalone vowel? How many repetitions of each case did you record? Did you try looking at monosyllables like [lo] and [bo]? Did you try words with other consonants?